# Select unicode character u2028 in mysql 5.1

Tags: mysql, unicode, utf-8

I am trying to select unicdode character /u2028 in MySQL 5.1. MySQL 5.1 does support utf8 and ucs2.

In newer versions of MySQL i could select the char just be using utf16 or utf32 collation:

```
SELECT char(0x2028 using utf16);
SELECT char(0x00002028 using utf32);
```

But MySQL 5.1 do not support utf16 and utf32. How could I select the unicode character then?

Perhaps a few words about my use case: I have an third party application which stores data in a mysql database and using JavaScript for user interface. The application do not deal with the problem unicode characters /u2028 and /u2029 are valid JSON but will break JavaScript code. (For details see http://timelessrepo.com/json-isnt-a-javascript-subset) So I like to know how much data is affected by that issue and perhaps use replace on MySQL to fix it.

---

To demonstrate the problem:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `string` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `string`) VALUES
(1, 'without U+2028'),
(2, 'with U+2028 at this "     "point');

SELECT * FROM test WHERE string LIKE CONCAT("%", char(0x2028 using utf16), "%");
// returns row 2 as expected

SELECT * FROM test WHERE string LIKE CONCAT("%", char(??? using utf8), "%");
// U+2028 in utf8 is 0xE2 0x80 0xA8 isn't it?
// But how to parse this to char function?
```

Comment: Not quite sure what the problem is. U+2028 is a character perfectly supported by the `utf8` encoding in MySQL. However, the `CHAR` function and its arguments is somewhat of a different topic. Why exactly to you want to convert the literal `0x2028` to the UTF-8 encoded U+2028 Unicode character? Is this *really* the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: U+2028 LINE SEPARATOR is rarely used. Are you sure you need to deal with it? It may cause problems in JavaScript, but how does this relate to MySQL?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela As I wrote in my use case I have to deal with U+2028 and U+2029 just because of problems they cause in JavaScript. I need to remove these characters of a MySQL database of a third party application because of JavaScript problems in the frontend.

Comment: @deceze: I added a demonstration of the problem to the question. In the end I like to write a find and replace query for all U+2028 and U+2029 characters.

Comment: I have more or less the same problem with 2028.  Would be interested in any solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The unicode character U+2028 can be encoded in UTF-8 as hexadecimal e280a8. So the answer is to use the UNHEX function in MySQL to find it.

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE string LIKE CONCAT("%", UNHEX('e280a8'), "%");
```

MySQL 5.1 can only handle characters encloded in UTF-8 up to three bytes long. So searching for U+2028 using UNHEX will work, but searching for U+1F600 won't as that takes up four bytes.

Use UNHEX('e280a9') to search for U+2029.

To find other characters, visit https://fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2028/index.htm, substituting '2028' for the character you are looking for. Look for the the number in brackets in the 'UTF-8 (hex)' row.

Comment: Where do you get / calculate the mapping between U+2028 and e280a8 ?  I have other characters I need to work on.

Comment: @Robert I've updated the answer to explain how to get the mappings for other characters.